# want to achieve multiple hollow diamonds with diagonal length, rows and columns specified by the user

Tags: python, loops

[image]

picture attached is my desired output from the following piece of code help needed regarding this .. or if you may share some of your code to achieve the results ,executable hollow diamond pattern but one* diamond only

```
c=int(input('Enter Column :'))
r=int(input('Enter Row :'))
n=int(input('Enter Odd Diagonal length :'))-1

j=n-1
print(' '*(n)+'*')
for i in range(1, 2*n):
    if i>n:
        print(' '*(i-n)+'*'+' '*(2*j-1)+'*')
        j-=1
    else:
        print(' '*(n-i)+'*'+' '*(2*i-1)+'*')
if n>1:
    print(' '*n+'*')
```

Comment: This code isn't runnable... could you fix the problems within the posted code?

Comment: What do you mean by diagonal length, there can be 2 diagonals here, so which one. Do you mean side length.

Comment: @Anwarvic issue fixed you may check now :)

Comment: @MandarA the diagonal length in picture is 3 three * diagonally for a diamond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are super close... Anyway, I fixed some issues and added a few lines in your code and everything works just fine:

```
c=int(input('Enter Column :'))
r=int(input('Enter Row :'))
n=int(input('Enter Odd Diagonal length :'))


for i in range(r):
    j=n-1
    print((' '*(n)+'*'+' '*(n+1))*c)
    for i in range(1, 2*n):
        if i>n:
            print((' '*(i-n)+'*'+' '*(2*j-1)+'*'+' '*(i-n+1))*c)
            j-=1
        else:
            print((' '*(n-i)+'*'+' '*(2*i-1)+'*'+' '*(n-i+1))*c)
    if n>=1:
        print((' '*n+'*'+' '*(n+1))*c)
```

Now, let's try it out:

```
>>> Enter Column : 4
>>> Enter Row : 2
>>> Enter Odd Diagonal length : 2
  *     *     *     *   
 * *   * *   * *   * *  
*   * *   * *   * *   * 
 * *   * *   * *   * *  
  *     *     *     *   
  *     *     *     *   
 * *   * *   * *   * *  
*   * *   * *   * *   * 
 * *   * *   * *   * *  
  *     *     *     *
```

Comment: and can i use if for confirming the diagonal length ... is the value entered even or odd

Comment: Why do you want the diagonal to be odd??

Comment: online exam requirements

Comment: Then you can add this check before the `for` loop